# Angular 9 SSR - Can we do SSR for only one module in a project?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

In my angular project, I have many modules. But I need to do SSR for only one module in the project. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I haven't tried but I guess you have to create a secondary AppModule with only the module you want to convert to SSR along with other necessary Angular and 3rd party modules. Then import this Secondary AppModule in the ServerModule for SSR. Though this might seem a possible solution, I beleive it might over-complicate the app.

Comment: Thanks Sharvan. I will try this.